# Is it possible to use sql database for BibTeX?

Tags: bibtex, database

I have and extensive database with references in form of an SQL database. How can I use this information in BibTeX?

Comment: I'd thought about asking the exact same thing myself...

Comment: Some clarification questions: 1) Do you want BibTeX to get the information _directly_ from the database, or are you prepared to extract it yourself in .bib format?  2) Do you already have the information in a database in a specific format and want to use only that, or would you be happy converting to another bibliographic database system?

Comment: I assume your database must have some particular schema; it would probably have been a good idea to mention what schema you are using or what tool you used to generate it...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nelson Beebe gave [a talk at TUG 2009](http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/tag/nelson-beebe/) on using SQL databases for bibliographic purposes as a replacement for BibTeX. The program is [bibsql](http://www.math.utah.edu/pub/bibsql/) and looks very promising, but I haven't used it myself.

You can read more details and examples in his paper in [TUGboat 30(2)](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Contents/contents30-2.html).

Comment: bibsql > linkrot

Comment: @nilon sorry to head :(

Answer (score 2):

One idea would be to use one of the many python APIs for SQL, and pipe that to one of the python modules that output bibtex